# Spotify Playback / Web player API

Tags: reactjs, spotify

I'm trying to make an app that play audio using spotify API

```
window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
        const token = 'MY_TOKEN';
        const player = new Spotify.Player({
            name: 'Web Playback SDK Quick Start Player',
            getOAuthToken: cb => { cb(token); },
            volume: .8,
        });

        // Ready
        player.addListener('ready', ({ device_id }) => {
           
            let config = {
                method:"PUT",
                headers:{
                    "Accept":"application/json",
                    "Content-Type":"application/json",
                    "Authorization": `Bearer BQANq8YSCLGLTg1wL7gIFNfcoX9wC7iQZhu9H3GoA2ZdaoHshW75fOQwGM5lfKER2Vf3wfroU4FQRZDI1LXwC3aDj9skstdX5vXumUkP_hM4Cz8fgFCjVKU4lh67ktz7VaGyoxCM5JxHa3PN9ih-1pkQEZRhG5YsGv6ErceGhdAd`
                },
                body:{
                    "context_uri": "spotify:album:5ht7ItJgpBH7W6vJ5BqpPr",
                    "position_ms": 0
                }
            }
            
            fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play?device_id=${device_id}`,config).then((res)=>{
                return res.json()
            }).then((data)=>{
                console.warn(data)
            })
        });
        player.connect();
    }
```

I got this but when I use the spotify console, no sound is playing but didn't get any error, when using code I got Malformed JSON response

Any idea ?

Comment: ... Are you sure the API gives you JSON and not some audio stream/format/data?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I'm using https://developer.spotify.com/console/put-play/

Comment: What if you get the response as text instead.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand